# Azure Devops Rest API - Variablegroups - Update - modify only one variable

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to update the value of a single variable of a variable group using Az DevOps Rest API. As per my initial experiments, it doesn't seem to be possible?

This is what I have tried:

Say I have a variable group called : `my-var-group` that has variables: `my-variable-1:val1`  `my-variable-2:val2` And if I try :

`curl -X  PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  'https://dev.azure.com/my-org/my-proj/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/201?api-version=5.1-preview.1'  --data '{"variables":{"my-variable-1":{"value":"random1"}},"name":"my-var-group"}'`

`my-variable-1` is assigned value `random1` but `my-variable-2` is deleted. Is there anyway to only update one variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here should be rather PATCH than PUT, but looking at documentation this is not possible.

I checked how it is done on Portal and there is used the same PUT endpoint as you mentioned. However, when you update there single value they still send all variables:

[image]

So as a workaround you may first get all variables, modify the one you need and send the back via PUT.

Other opiton could be [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#az_pipelines_variable_group_variable_update)

```
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id
                                            --name
                                            [--detect {false, true}]
                                            [--new-name]
                                            [--org]
                                            [--project]
                                            [--prompt-value {false, true}]
                                            [--secret {false, true}]
                                            [--subscription]
                                            [--value]
```

which allows you to update single value. However, I don't know if this is an option for you.